# passing value from one form to another in codeigniter from database using session

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session

Have a issue passing value from one form to another form.I have implemented a session for the same but have a problem fetching the value from form one to second form.I need help passing  the primary key(in the database) associated with the data to another forms textbox.Also need help of how to pass the primary key using a session to another form...Pls help.

form1 controller

```
$this->view_data['pk'] = $this->form_1_model->input(); //pk is the name of the textbox wherein the value should be passed
$this->load->view('form_2' , $this->view_data );
```

form2 controller

```
 $data['pk'] = $this -> form1_model -> input();
    $this->load->view('form2_view');
```

But using this only passes the primary key value to the form 2 and does not load my dynamic fields
 **using a redirect does not load the text box in which value is to be passed**  but loads he form correctly.
So now i have implemented session but dont know how to implement it to pass the value

Comment: Please can you provide some of your code so we can see what you have done/tried?

Comment: Please post what you had try

Comment: Done @Renier... and Maulik patel

Comment: you need to show us your form_1_model and signup_model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions.

Add values to session

```
$this->session->set_userdata('KEY','VALUE');
```

Retrieve values from session

```
$value=$this->session->userdata('KEY');
```

Comment: i need to display it in the textbox how can i do that? 
`<?php 
foreach ( $pk as $row )
{
 echo '<input id="pk" type="text" readonly name="pk" value="'.$row->pkUser.'">';
 
 echo "<br />";
}?>`
i was using this previously without initializing session

Comment: load the values to a data array in controller,then loads it to the view.Then simply get the values in a foreach loop as you have doe above

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use `$this->session->set_userdata('key',value);`
or something tricky like putting `<input type="hidden" value="yourvalue">`

Comment: the primary key value needs to be changed for every new entry so cannot give the value

Answer (score 0):

Session is the best option:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('key',value);
```

Or any other state management techniques can be used to use it for future use.